# Can I skip a catch block under certain conditions in a try/catch?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I have a function which gets given a list of ids and then `maps` over that list and calls an API for each one:

```
let fullDetails: Array<any> = [];
ids.map(async (id) => {
  try {
    const result = await api.getFullDetails(id);
    if (result.data) fullDetails.push(result.data);
  } catch {
    // Handle error
  }
});
```

The problem I'm having is that sometimes the `getFullDetails` function will return an error just because the record it's looking for doesn't exist.   But, I don't really care if the record doesn't exist (to be honest, I don't really care about any errors here) - I'm happy to just skip that one and move on to the next.  No matter what I do, though, my code seems to bail out at that point if the result is an error.

I've tried leaving out the `try-catch` block, but then I get a 'Possible unhandled Promise rejection' error and `fullDetails` remains empty (although I know for sure that one of the ids worked ok).

I also tried rewriting to use `Promise.all`, like this:

```
 let results = ids.map((id) =>
        api.getFullDetails(id),
      );
      Promise.all(results)
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result);
        })
        .catch((error) => { console.log('Error')});
```

but again, it goes into the catch block if there's any kind of error.  Again I tried leaving out the catch block here, but then I got the 'Possible unhandled Promise rejection' error again, and the result was never shown.

Is there a way to handle this (apart form rewriting the API to not return an error)?  Basically I just don't want to check for errors at all, and just ignore them if they occur.

Comment: You could just leave the catch empty?

Comment: Thanks, but if I do that I get the 'Unhandled Promise Rejection' error again, and it bails out.

Comment: You could try doing a console.warn inside the catch block. Also note that catch needs parenthesis like a function: `catch(err){ ... }`

Comment: As soon as I add a catch, it goes into it when it hits the error.  I suspect I'm doing something silly in the code, but I just can't see what it is!

Comment: Is the error caused by a linter? If so you could just disable that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to use map with async is to use one of the Promise's methods.
It's better to choose [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) rather than `Promise.all()` in your case. Because, according to MDN,

> In comparison, the Promise returned by Promise.all() may be more appropriate if the tasks are dependent on each other, or if you'd like to immediately reject upon any of them rejecting.

Meaning the former case won't reject promises and stop the program execution.

Note that the `allSettled()` returns an object with two of this three properties:

```
[{
  reason: "Id must be non-negative",
  status: "rejected"
}, {
  status: "fulfilled",
  value: 2
}]
```

The first case happens when the Promise is rejected and the second when it's fullfiled.

```
Promise.allSettled(ids.map((id) =>  api.getFullDetails(id))).then(x => {   
  let fullDetails = x.map(({value})=>value).filter(Boolean)
  console.log(fullDetails)
})
```

As seen in this working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/p8a0mvr4/).